# App.Current.MainWindow changes when launching another dialog?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, mef

I am launching a new dialog from a MEF plugin when I start up the application.  Could someone explain why this changes `App.Current.MainWindow` to the dialog that was launched from the plugin?  How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you post some example startup code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out App.Current.MainWindow gets set to the first window that is launched.  I was launching the plugin dialog before the main window.